# ClassNotFoundException in Spark when a newer version was installed

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I tried to read `csv`, `json` and `parquet` files using `spark`. However, in each case, I'm getting the error listed at the end of the question.

I've tried running the following in `spark-shell`:

```scala
val df = spark.read.csv('a.csv')
```

I've also tried running the following in `pyspark`:

```py
df = spark.read.csv('a.csv')
```

I get the same error for all file types.
The `spark-version` I'm using is `2.4.0`, with a packaged `bin-hadoop-2.7`.

I also have `spark-2.3.3` installed. However, my environment variables like `SPARK_HOME` have been edited to point to the `spark-2.4.4` installation.

When I export `SPARKHOME` to point to the `spark-2.3.3` version, everything works fine. So this is some issue with installation.

I'm not sure what changes should I make for `spark-2.4.0` to start working?

`pyspark` throws the same error too, with an additional line in beginning:

```
py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o30.json.
```

Error:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/spark/sql/execution/datasources/v2/FileDataSourceV2
  at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
  at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:763)
  at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
  at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:468)
  at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:74)
  at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:369)
  at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:363)
  at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
  at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:362)
  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
  at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:349)
  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:411)
  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:411)
  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
  at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
  at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:348)
  at java.util.ServiceLoader$LazyIterator.nextService(ServiceLoader.java:370)
  at java.util.ServiceLoader$LazyIterator.next(ServiceLoader.java:404)
  at java.util.ServiceLoader$1.next(ServiceLoader.java:480)
  at scala.collection.convert.Wrappers$JIteratorWrapper.next(Wrappers.scala:43)
  at scala.collection.Iterator$class.foreach(Iterator.scala:891)
  at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:1334)
  at scala.collection.IterableLike$class.foreach(IterableLike.scala:72)
  at scala.collection.AbstractIterable.foreach(Iterable.scala:54)
  at scala.collection.TraversableLike$class.filterImpl(TraversableLike.scala:247)
  at scala.collection.TraversableLike$class.filter(TraversableLike.scala:259)
  at scala.collection.AbstractTraversable.filter(Traversable.scala:104)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource$.lookupDataSource(DataSource.scala:630)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.load(DataFrameReader.scala:194)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.json(DataFrameReader.scala:391)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.json(DataFrameReader.scala:325)
  ... 49 elided
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.v2.FileDataSourceV2
  at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:382)
  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
  at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:349)
  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
  ... 80 more
```

Answer (score 1):

[FileDataSourceV2](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/v3.0.0/sql/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/execution/datasources/v2/FileDataSourceV2.scala) is a trait that was introduced in a later version of Spark, so it showing up suggests that you could be using the wrong binaries to launch your context.

I would ensure that

- The `$PATH` variable doesn't contain any conflicting binaries.

  - If you are using spark-shell: `type spark-shell || which spark-shell` produces the expected result. If not, you may want to run $SPARK_HOME/bin/spark-shell directly, instead.
  - If you are using spark-submit directly: `type spark-submit || which spark-submit` produces the expected result.
  - If `echo $PATH` contains paths with conflicting binaries, you may want to set the path to a much simpler one, or at least remove conflicting paths, such as `.../anaconda3/bin/` (for example, if using anaconda).
- `$SPARK_HOME/conf/spark-defauls.conf` doesn't have any options that could add conflicting jars from anywhere. Check for `spark.driver.extraClassPath` and similar configurations that could add conflicting jars.
- Do the same check for the environment variable for options: `echo $SPARK_SUBMIT_OPTS`